# graph editor -> how to mirror this?

Tags: graph-editor

[image]

I now, with T i can choose my keyframe interpolation, which is great.

But i just want it to flip. What is a quick way to do that?

Goal:

[image]

My pictures might be misleading, sorry for that.

x and y values of all keyframes should stay the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you press Ctrl+E you see the options for ease in an out options. In your case it would be "Ease out" option.

[image: Ease types]

Comment: that easy ‍♂️ thank you!! works!!